# What does pointing an object at NULL place the member values at?

Tags: c++, class, oop, null

Sorry about the wordy title.

```
class Student
{
public:
// Some routines

private:
string name;
int grade;
}
```

In the main:

```
Student* newStudent = NULL;
```

I know that NULL is the same as zero, but what are name and grade set at now? When I do:

```
cout << newStudent->getName();
```

it does not return 0 - instead, Visual Studio gives me some kind of error.

So I'm also wondering, what is newStudent pointing at exactly? Has it just kind of eliminated all the private data, and is pointing the entire class at 0?

EDIT:

Ok chris - that's kind of what I thought. My follow up question is then:
How do I check for this in the getName function.

I can't use a bool like,

```
if (name == 0)
// Return an error message.
```

so is there a work-around for this?

EDIT:
The VS error is:
Unhandled exception at 0x00FFAAA6 in Ex8_3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000014.

Be aware that this is actually part of a much larger program, I've just isolated the problem part.

EDIT:
OK, here is the code that is causing problems. I'll just post the whole program since it is not too large, and I could use any constructive criticism I can get on it anyways.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    // Accessor
    string getName();
    vector<string> getCourseList();
    Student* getLink();

    // Mutators
    void setName (string aName);        
    void setCourses(vector<string> list);       
    void setLink (Student* aLink);

private:
    string name;
    vector<string> courseList;      
    Student* link;

};

// Linked-list Non-Member Functions.
typedef Student* NodePtr;
void head_insert (NodePtr& head); 
NodePtr search (NodePtr head, string target); 
NodePtr searchPrevious (NodePtr head, string target);
void deleteNode (NodePtr& head, string target);
void show_list (NodePtr& head);
void showFirstCourses (NodePtr& head);

int main()
{
    NodePtr headPointer = NULL;
    head_insert(headPointer);
    headPointer->setName("Tim");

    head_insert(headPointer);
    headPointer->setName("Jan");

    head_insert(headPointer);
    headPointer->setName("Jim");

    deleteNode(headPointer, "Tim");

    NodePtr test1 = NULL;
    head_insert(test1);     // This is where the new Student is created.

    test1 = search (headPointer, "Jon");    // Still experiencing a problem between here and the next instruction.

    cout << test1->getName();   // Something is wrong if this == NULL.


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

string Student::getName()
{
    return name;
}

vector<string> Student::getCourseList()
{
    return courseList;
}

Student* Student::getLink()
{
    return link;
}

void Student::setName (string aName)
{
    name = aName;
}

void Student::setCourses(vector<string> list)
{
    courseList = list;
}

void Student::setLink (Student* aLink)
{
    link = aLink;
}

void head_insert (NodePtr& head)
{
    NodePtr temp_ptr; 
    temp_ptr = new Student; 
    temp_ptr->setLink(head);    // Link this to what the head is linking to.
    head = temp_ptr;    // Use this node as the new head.
}

NodePtr search (NodePtr head, string target)        // Needs to be tested, to see if getLink is working correctly.
{
    // Point to the head node 
    NodePtr here = head; 

    // If the list is empty nothing to search 
    if (here == NULL) 
    { 
        return NULL; 
    } 
    // Search for the item 
    else 
    { 
        // while you have still items and you haven't found the target yet 
        while (here->getName() != target && here->getLink() != NULL) 
            here = here->getLink(); 
         // Found the target, return the pointer at that location 
         if (here->getName() == target) 
                return here; 
         // Search unsuccessful, return Null 
         else 
                return NULL; 
    } 
}

NodePtr searchPrevious (NodePtr head, string target)    // This function needs to be checked for the same things the above function does.
{
    // Point to the head node 
    NodePtr here = head; 

    // If the list is empty nothing to search 
    if (here == NULL) 
    { 
        return NULL; 
    } 
    // Search for the item 
    else 
    { 
        // while you still have items and you haven't found the target yet 
        while (here->getName() !=target && (here->getLink())->getName() != target && (here->getLink())->getLink() != NULL)
            here = here->getLink(); 
         // Found the target, return the pointer at that location 
        if (((here->getLink())->getName() == target) || (here->getName() == target))
        {
            return here;
        }
         // Search unsuccessful, return Null 
         else 
                return NULL; 
    } 
}

void deleteNode (NodePtr& head, string target)      
{
    NodePtr toBeDeleted = search (head, target);
    NodePtr previousPointer = searchPrevious (head, target);

    // Make sure the desired value is in the list.
    if (toBeDeleted ==  NULL)
    {
        cout << target << " is not in the list, so it can't be deleted.\n";
        return;
    }

    // Test to see if we are removing the first node.
    if (previousPointer == toBeDeleted)
    {
        head = toBeDeleted->getLink();
        delete toBeDeleted;
        return;
    }

    // Connect the node from before to after.
    previousPointer->setLink(toBeDeleted->getLink());

    delete toBeDeleted;
}
```

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. A null pointer doesn't point to a valid object to call `getName()` on.

Comment: Yes its undefined and rightly so. BTW Could you share what is the error VS is giving for this.

Comment: Big thing here: NULL does not mean the same as zero! Zero is a value. It's a number that can be contained in a variable. NULL is the lack of a variable.

Comment: Each member variable in a class is assigned an offset in the class.  You can use offsetof() to get the offset.  To access a member variable the compiler will add the member offset to the pointer value.  In your example, name might have offset 0 and grade offset 4.  With newStudent = 0, the address of name is address+offset (0+0) and the address of grade would be (0+4), both are usually invalid address and accessing them is undefined.

Comment: Objects don't point at anything. Pointers point to objects, *or* are zero, in which case there is no object and no contents. Your question just results from getting the terminology backwards.

Comment: VS is rightly pointing to the error. The reference variable newStudent is not pointing to a valid Student object, instead it's pointing to a NULL which and hence VS is raising the error.

Comment: @ciphermagi NULL *is* zero in C, and therefore in C++ programs that use the C header in which it is defined, and Bjarne Stroustrup has stated there is no need to use NULL at all in a well written C++ program. You can conclude that NULL isn't part of C++ at all.

Comment: @EJP `int x = 5 + 0;` What's wrong with this? `int x = 5 + NULL;` What about this?

Comment: @EJP, Actually, it can be something like `(void *)0` in C, whereas in C++, it must be an integral constant that evaluates to zero.

Comment: @cipermagee It doesn't make sense, if that's what you're getting at, but nobody has said otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think of `name` and `grade` on a pointer that points to NULL as set to something. When a `Student *` pointer is set to NULL, it points at nothing. It's as if you pointed to an empty space in a room and asked me what the name of the person you are pointing at is.

You can't dereference a NULL pointer, so doing this:

```
Student *s = NULL;
s->name;
```

is undefined behavior. Anything could happen; most likely, you'll get a segfault. (But this is an implementation detail, and not guaranteed.)

You *can* check for null, simply with:

```
if(s) {
    // s isn't NULL.
}
```

(You can also use `if(s != NULL)`, or `if(s != nullptr)`.)

Now that we've got your code, let's look at this case:

```
test1 = search (headPointer, "Jon");    // Still experiencing a problem between here and the next instruction.

cout << test1->getName();   // Something is wrong if this == NULL.
```

The problem here is the second line: in the case that the search fails, why to you expect to be able to output the student's name? We haven't found a student! We need to handle the lack of having a student:

```
test1 = search(headPointer, "Jon");
if(test1) {
    cout << "Found student; his name is " << test1->getName() << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Couldn't find that student." << endl;
}
```

Similarly, we have some bad logic here:

```
while (here->getName() != target && here->getLink() != NULL) 
    here = here->getLink();
```

Let's say that `here->getLink()` returns NULL in the inevitable case that we hit the end of this list. The condition in the `while` (`here->getName()`) now dereferences an invalid (NULL) pointer. Let's restructure this entire function significantly:

```
NodePtr search (NodePtr head, string target) {
    // Where in the list we are:
    NodePtr here = head;
    // Check that head points at a student:
    while(here != NULL) {
        // Check if this is the student we are searching for:
        if(here->getName() == target) {
            // It is. Great! Return him/her:
            return head;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Note that unless you're required to implement a linked list, the STL (the standard template library) has several list containers: `std::list` and `std::vector` are two containers that contain lists of objects. They have different performance characteristics, and you'll need to choose between those, but they're going to be a lot easier to use than re-inventing a linked list.

One last thing:

> OK I can take that solution, I was just thinking there might be a more elegant solution - like including this check in the getName function if possible. The reason being, is that I would have to include the check you described above every time I call getName.

Let's talk about `getName`. *If* we allow a NULL student in that function, what do we do? Since we can't get the name of the student we don't have... it's pretty hard to say. Do we output an error? Raise an exception? Kill the program?

In member functions, it is typically fair game to expect that the object you're operating on exists. If it doesn't, it's a bug in the caller for doing `->getName()` on a NULL pointer. Similarly, in normal functions, we can take a reference:

```
void do_something_with_a_student(Student &s)
```

References shouldn't be NULL, and so this function is allowed to assume that it always has a valid student. The only places you need to worry about "do I have a valid student?" are places where that concern should logically arise, such as just having searched for a student. If I search my class roster for a "Billy", I might or might not have such a student: here, we need that "does not exist" value; NULL is useful for that.

Even if you take a pointer, you can always document (with a comment, perhaps) that the function only allows non-NULL pointers. This is more common in C, which lacks references; in C++, references are a better choice.

Comment: Thank you for the checking for null comment! How would I do this from a member function of Student?

Comment: Typically in member functions, you should assume that `this` (the object you're dealing with) is valid. If it isn't, then some *other* code has a bug. For your example of `getName`, assuming that caller isn't calling `getName()` on a NULL pointer is reasonable. (If the caller is, what are you going to do about it?)

Comment: If your object has created properly, you do no need to worry about the member function/data.

Comment: Well, newStudent = NULL is the result of a failed search function, which is followed in the code by outputting the name of the student searched for (newStudent->getName()). So, obviously I'm doing something improperly - I do not know what though.

Comment: @featherlight53 Do you have `newStudent = new Student;` anywhere?

Comment: Yep. This occurs before the search function is called though. The function then fails, and returns null in the fashion: newStudent = new Student; newStudent = search("NotThere"); cout << newStudent->getName();

Comment: @featherlight53: Could you update your question to show us the code that calls `search`, and the body of `search` itself?

Comment: OK it's all up there.

Comment: OK I can take that solution, I was just thinking there might be a more elegant solution - like including this check in the getName function if possible. The reason being, is that I would have to include the check you described above *every time* I call getName.

Comment: Yeah that logic restructuring is a lot better. I'll put that in, along with it in the searchPrevious function.

Comment: @featherlight53: I've tried address your last concern as well.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is not an object.  It is an address of an object.  Like a street address.

When you call `new MyObject()`, two things happen: an object is created (somewhere), then the address of this object is returned.

A pointer whose value is null is an address that reads "no such address", or is a blank address.  When you use this null pointer, you tell the language "I guarantee this address is good, now use it".  As your guarantee is a lie, undefined behaviour results (often a crash, but there is no guarantee).

There are no member functions or data at a blank address to have a value.  What you did was the equivalent of telling a blind pilot to set their coordinates to the middle of the pacific, land their plane there, and then get out, walk into the house 30 feet away, and pick up the banana on the counter (next to the toaster oven).

There is no banana, no house, and no runway where you told the pilot to go.  So things go poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a pointer to point to null is a way of "resetting" a pointer back to pointing at nothing. When you are doing newStudent->getName(), you are accessing the newStudent class and calling a function inside it. If newStudent points to nothing, then there are no functions inside it to call, since it isn't even pointing at anything. Once you give it a class object to point to, then you can call the getName() function inside it. You can think of NULL (nullptr) as the same as saying, "I am pointing at NULL, so you cannot and should not use me for anything, since there is nothing here to begin with". You can test this by doing "pointer == nullptr". Remember, you cannot assume anything about NULL, it isn't zero, it isn't anything, because it's undefined except for the fact that it is NULL.